# Cannot load Google API Client on Ruby on Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, google-plus-signin

I want to verify user profile from Google Authorization code sent by android client, to do that, we have to download client_secrets.json and put it inside our rails app. Just like this tutorial https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

But when I try to follow this step

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'

client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
auth_client.update!(
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
  :redirect_uri => 'http://www.example.com/oauth2callback',
  :additional_parameters => {
    "access_type" => "offline",         # offline access
    "include_granted_scopes" => "true"  # incremental auth
  }
)
```

Rails throws an error said "**No client_secrets.json filename supplied and/or could not be found in search path.**"
The errors shows up even though I have insert client_secrets.json inside config/client_secrets.json

Do you know what's the problem or what's the alternative for this solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[It seems](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/lib/google/api_client/client_secrets.rb), `ClientSecrets.load` accepts optional argument which is config filename path. So I believe it's okay if you specify filename directly:

```
Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("#{Rails.root}/config/client_secrets.json")
```